# I want to know how to sort the dates in objective c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

how to sort date using nsarray ? I have four dates , that should by display by ascending order.can you explain how to sort ? I searched so many stuff, but i can't ablt to find any thing .Please help me , is there any method for date sort.

Comment: Did you try the documentation for `NSArray` (http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) in all that stuff you searched?

Comment: Have you seen this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302627/sorting-by-date-format-in-iphone ?  Also, this appears to be a duplicate of this recent question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334150/iphone-how-to-sort-dates-using-nsdate.

Answer (score 5):

`NSDate`'s `compare:` method already does what you want.  Try:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [unsortedArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```